# Batman comic where Dick Grayson is killed?

Tags: story-identification, dc, batman

I read this Batman comic a long time back, I think around 2002.

Anyways the story starts out with batman in some kinda dark room. It looks like a Torture room or something. Batman wakes up and to his shock finds Robin (Dick Grayson) dead with face skin peeled off and bruises all over his body.

There is also some kinda TV monitor in the room. It turns on and we see Harvey Dent. Harvey Dents smirks at Batman. The scene kinda implies that Harvey Dent killed Robin. It then cuts to flashbacks.

The first flashback basically shows how Bruce Wayne's parents were killed. But, it's weird that here a homeless kid kills Bruce's parents. Bruce for some reason can't seem to remember his face. They show a Black spot for his face. Then most of the story follows Bruce becoming Batman fighting foes like Scarecrow, Penguin, Clay Face and Riddler. He also works with Gordon sometimes.

He eventually recruits Dick Grayson as Robin and they both work together to solve cases and fight crimes. They also go up against Poison Ivy and Black Mask. And at the same time Harvey Dent is also introduced. The youngest District Attorney in Gotham City. Harvey Dent is able to bring down crime in Gotham city to all time low. Harvey is also shown to be extremely confident and there is this sort of overwhelming confidence and pressure he exerts when you are around him. A lot of people hate his Guts.

With crime becoming all time low, I think, Batman gives up his career as he sees there is no need for him. He sort of goes into seclusion and depression. Robin meanwhile still continues on but not as Robin but with his own identity as "Shadow Warrior". And, I think somewhere around here The Joker is also comes into picture.

So, I don't remember exactly what happens then but I think Dick Grayson decides to go against The Joker on his own but he gets captured by him. And, I think Bruce wayne finds out about it somehow or something and returns as Batman to find out Joker's location.

I think he eventually finds out the location and it leads back to the start of the story where he is in the torture room. He remembers that the Joker catches him off gaurd and hit him the head with a rod or something.

We are then back to where the story starts out. Batman asks Harvey whether he is the Joker or was he working with Joker. Harvey says no but he somewhat toys around with him or something like that.

Then eventually Harvey Dent says that he and Batman are very similar. Similar in the sense that they both have a very dirty side towards them. Batman disagrees and dismisses it. Harvey then responds by saying that Bruce Knows who killed his parents and his just in denial of the truth.

I think Batman then starts to remember and eventually realizes that he was the one who killed his parents. Batman is in tears and his in denial with himself.

Batman then suddenly starts laughing maniacally. For a brief few minutes he even talks like Gordon. Then he starts to laugh and cry realizing he has also killed Dick grayson.

I think it is implied that Batman, The Joker and Gordon are all the same and just different personalities of Bruce Wayne.

Harvey Dent, while smirking at Batman, tells him again that they both are similar in the sense that they both have a very dirty and nasty side of them.

Harvey Dent then reveals that he likes to play around and toy with people. His greatest pleasure is in destroying the things that he loves the most. He doesn't care about winning or losing. Right or wrong. He also tells that he feels only happiness when people hate him. He wants people to hate him.

Harvey then also reveals that he won't reveal anything to the public or anyone because he wants to see now what Bruce/Batman/The Joker/Gordon is going to him now that he has  destroyed him.

The TV monitor turns off. And Batman is seen just crying, laughing and trying to calm himself. The comic I think ends there. Unless there is another part or something. And that's all I really remember.

Comment: Well, this certainly wouldn't be part of "regular Batman continuity" unless it turned out an author was indulging himself with something *crazy* that would be revealed in the next issue to be a drug-induced nightmare or something similar. That suggests an Elseworlds, or some similar built-in excuse for offering a shocking self-contained story that was never meant to have any impact on "regular continuity." I don't recognize the story; I'm just making some observations which might jog someone else's memory or help narrow the field. (If I run across this one, I'll come back and say so.)